# Adding values from different rows that are tied to a specific primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add option amounts that are tied to a specific primary key that is then added as a column at the end. Here is my code. I have the Retail Cost getting the max value.

```
SELECT
    AppDetailVehicleValuation.AppID, 
    VehicleValuationOption.Description AS AddOn, 
    MAX(VehicleValuationOptionValueType.Value) AS RetailCost
FROM            
    AppDetailVehicleValuation
    INNER JOIN VehicleValuationOption 
        ON AppDetailVehicleValuation.ValuationID = VehicleValuationOption.ValuationID 
    INNER JOIN VehicleValuationOptionValueType 
        ON VehicleValuationOption.ValuationOptionID = VehicleValuationOptionValueType.ValuationOptionID
WHERE        
    (VehicleValuationOption.IsSelected LIKE '1') 
    AND (VehicleValuationOption.IsSystemOption LIKE '1')
GROUP BY VehicleValuationOption.Description, AppDetailVehicleValuation.AppID
```

Here is what I have.

```
AppID | AddOn       | RetailCost
999     Beats Audio   475.00
999     Safety Tek    675.00
1052    Tinted Win    850.00
1052    18in Rims     1600.00
1052    Matte Pt.     950.00
```

This is what I want to achieve.

```
AppID | AddOn       | RetailCost   | AddOnTotal
999     Beats Audio   475.00         1150.00
999     Safety Tek    675.00         1150.00
1052    Tinted Win    850.00         3400.00
1052    18in Rims     1600.00        3400.00
1052    Matte Pt.     950.00         3400.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
select appid, addon, retailcost,
       sum(retailcost) over (partition by appid) as addontotal
from t;
```